# How to mount Rails 3 application to an existing Rails 2.3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2, rails-engines

I have a Rails 2.3 App. My requirement is simple, I need to mount Rails new version 3.2 to my existing Rails 2.3 version. Is it possible? Can I use Rails Engines for that ? Finally I want major portion of my app is in Rails 2.3 and some new portions / functionality in Rails 3.2 without updating my Rails 2.3 version. Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 2):

A Guide is the part screen-cast series on Rails-casts by Ryan Bates

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2
http://railscasts.com/episodes/227-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-3
```

ASCII-CASTS :

```
http://asciicasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/227-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-3
```

Comment: This is not the exact answer. But this helped me little bit. thanks.

Comment: Railscasts is a great resource but this doesn't really answer the question.  How do you mount a rails 3.2 engine inside a rails 2.3 app? Is it even possible?